# Why Android kernel compilation needs both GCC and Clang?

Tags: android, gcc, clang, kernel, android-source

Every tutorial I find about Android Kernel compilation (like this: https://gist.github.com/P1N2O/b9b2604c58aa4d7486e2fc0d327d23dc) does things like this:

```
make O=out ARCH=arm64 <defconfig>

PATH="<path to clang folder>/bin:<path to gcc folder>/bin:${PATH}" \
make -j$(nproc --all) O=out \
                      ARCH=arm64 \
                      CC=clang \
                      CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- \
                      CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
```

where `CLANG_TRIPLE` are things from GCC's bin folder. Why is GCC still needed? By the way, what does `CLANG_TRIPLE` and `CROSS_COMPILE` mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I think you don't need gcc, what you need are the binutils